# UITextView resignFirstResponder on didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have in IB static `UITableView` and when I click on cell I want to hide keyboard. 
When `isFirstResponder` is `UITextField` it's OK!
But when `UITextView` it doesn't work :(

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [publicationTextView resignFirstResponder];
    //[self.view endEditing:YES];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Add a breakpoint to [publicationTextView resignFirstResponder];.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to hide keyboard for textfield try setting isEditable to "NO" during adding subview to cell 
i,e

```
     //- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView   cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
    UITextView *aTv = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 300)];
    aTv.text = @"textView";
    aTv.delegate = self;
    [aTv setEditable:NO]; //avoid appearing of key board when tap on the text field
    [cell addSubview:aTv];
```

// hope this helps

Comment: Yep!
This help!
[textView setEditable:NO];